# Trouble with assembly code

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

So I have been learning assembly and working on a small project for class.
Its a simple program that multiples two numbers without using the built in mult instruction. Instead it does so by shift adding. But I am having trouble making it display the result in the QtSpim console.

```
.text

main:

li $v0, 0
li $t0, 1
li $t1, 0
li $a0, 2
li $a1, 3

main_loop:

    beq $a1, $zero, main_end
    beq $a0, $zero, main_end

    and $t1, $t0, $a1
    beq $t1, 1, main_do_add
    beq $t1, 0, main_do_shift

    main_do_add:
        addu $v0, $v0, $a0

    main_do_shift:
        sll $a0, $a0, 1
        srl $a1, $a1, 1

    j main_loop

main_end:
    li $v0, 10
```

I am very new to assembly and this is first real piece of program. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Having trouble as in "don't know where to start"?  In future, you should say what you've tried, or even show one of your failed attempts in code with comments explaining what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to print the value.

Here's the corrected and annotated program. Note: I did *not* check your multiply logic, but the result was 6, so I'm guessing that's what you wanted.

I recommend adding sidebar comments to almost every asm line so you can follow your logic and compare it against the instructions you use to implement it.

Anyway, here's the code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .text

main:

    li      $v0,0
    li      $t0,1
    li      $t1,0
    li      $a0,2
    li      $a1,3

main_loop:

    beq     $a1,$zero,main_end
    beq     $a0,$zero,main_end

    and     $t1,$t0,$a1
    beq     $t1,1,main_do_add
    beq     $t1,0,main_do_shift

main_do_add:
    addu    $v0,$v0,$a0

main_do_shift:
    sll     $a0,$a0,1
    srl     $a1,$a1,1

    j       main_loop

main_end:
    # BUGFIX -- this was missing
    move    $a0,$v0                     # get result to argument register
    li      $v0,1                       # print integer
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                      # exit program
    syscall
```